# mapping path parameters in RKPaginator request in object manager

Tags: restkit

I am able to map path parameters correctly using following code if it is not RKPaginator request.

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:className inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
[mapping setIdentificationAttributes:@[@"id"]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"@metadata.routing.parameters.id": @"entityId",
    @"@metadata.mapping.collectionIndex": @"itemIndex",
    .... other mapping attributes
}];

RKResponseDescriptor* learningObjRd = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping 
    method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"entity/:entityId" keyPath:@"objects" 
    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[self.objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:
    [RKRoute routeWithName:@"learningObjects" pathPattern:@"entity/:id" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];
[self.objectManager getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:@"learningObjects" object:@{@"id":entityId} 
    parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {}];
```

While using RKPaginator, I could not find a way to add named routes. So I user url to create paginator

```
RKPaginator* paginator = [self.objectManager paginatorWithPathPattern:@"series?page=:currentPage&count=:perPage" 
    parameters:nil];
[paginator loadPage:1];
```

Is there any way to specify parameters in URL which can also be used on mapping?

Comment: why would you be paginating with an explicit id? i guess you'll need to do some subclassing...

Comment: I want to fetch data from url as /entity?page=1&count=10&type=:type I want to map this type locally

Comment: you can map parameters using metadata

Comment: I could not find any way to specify value of parameters while making request using paginator.

Comment: hence the subclassing comment

Comment: Can you tell me something more about subclassing? I made category of RKPaginator to add additional property. But restkit could not find it since i would not include that category.